# How do I display a google captcha in java?

Tags: java

I just tried to create a program with HTMLUnit, which can log into a website (It can do more, of course, but that is the most important thing about it) with user entered data. Unfortunately, the website always redirects me to a website, where I have to enter a google captcha to continue. Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some.website/login");
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"section-main\"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Login");
        final HtmlTextInput email = form.getInputByName("username");
        final HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) form.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"section-main\"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[4]/input").get(0);
        email.setValueAttribute("some@email.com");
        password.setValueAttribute("aPassword");
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    }
```

It does not work, it returns a NullPointerException for the button, email and password, since it can't find the form. I know JDownloader has built something similar, but it is not available on the download page. So, my question is: How do I display a captcha to the user and let them enter the words?

Comment: JDownloader sourcecode _is_ available : http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/development/get-started.
Please dont state your assumptions like if they were facts, thank you very much.

Comment: This hurts me so much: `final HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) form.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"section-main\"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[4]/input").get(0);`

Comment: Yeah, someone had the great idea to put a script in there which changes the password name attribute every time you reload, so I had to do it... But honestly, I don't know why I didn't put getFirstByXpath there... AND @specializt if you try to click "JD-Source" on the download site (http://jdownloader.org/download/index) it tells you "Redmine 404 error Page not found". I didn't know there was a second mirror, as there is only one mirror listed.

Comment: @MisterX you clearly have not even looked at the wiki-page at all. The official repository is at svn://svn.jdownloader.org/jdownloader. I think your task is a little bit too complex for you right now ...

Comment: I now know how to do it (thanks to antonios) and it isn't too complex for me. I searched for other questions similar to mine and it found a question linking to the download page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse page with captcha and get link to the captcha image. Later on you need to fetch the content of image data and create `BufferedImage` with `ImageIO`. Last step would be creating a window `JFrame` and show captcha for the user. Perfect solution would be to prompt for imput and post the answer. Yes it is possible, I have implemented exactly the same solution in the past.